# Use APACHE to host website on Mac

Tags: macos, apache

I have done research on how to use Apache on newer Mac OS (with a lot of terminal commands). But all tutorials I have seen stop at `localhost` example. I have a registered domain name already and would like to use that domain to publish the website.

So the end result should be, when I type `www.xxx.com`, I would be able to see the webpages I wrote. How may I do this? Where should I save all my HTML, CSS, JavaScript files?

Thank you.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here to help you set up a server.

Comment: With what little knowledge you seem to have about the whole thing, it would be better if you hosted your site somewhere on a hosting platform set up by people who know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a copy of OS X Server. You need to configure it to host your web services.

Then you need to set up the A record for the site with domain registrar (who you registered the domain with). This will put the address lookup for your domain name to your machine out on the internet. As a result of this step users who type in your domain name will have their traffic routed to your machine. If you haven't done the first step, the traffic will go no where and they will not get a response.